# how to write query for row to column in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot-table, unpivot

I have table customer

```
 customerno   sname   contactid  address
  1           aaa       101       north
  1            bbb      102        south
  1            ccc       103       west
  2           ddd        104       south
  2           ccc        105       north
  2            eee        106       null
```

i want to convert particular customer detail into single line.
i want result like

```
Customerno    sname1    sname2   sname3  address1  address2     address3
  1            aaa       bbb      ccc     north     south         west
  2            ddd       ccc      eee     south      north         null
```

help me ........

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar in nature to the question below. Please look at the answers for guidance. Since you are "pivoting" across more than 1 column, I think this problem can only be solved with a number of self joins.

[Convert rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271188/convert-rows-to-columns)

Not to bias you, here is my answer :) ...

[Convert rows to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271188/convert-rows-to-columns/4271707#4271707)

Comment: I should add that the above solution only works where you have a known bound or limit of entries you want to pivot for each customerno in the table as this will be dictated by the number of self joins you make